# Problems installing pybrain on anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, pybrain

Can somebody tell me what the issue is and how do I resolve it?

```
Unsatisfiable error:The following specifications were found to be in conflict

-pybrain->python 3.4*->vc 10.*
-python 3.6
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide following details?

1. python version
2. confirm if it is windows OS ?

Comment: python version is 3.6(Anaconda version is 4.3.1) and yes it is a windows 8 operating system.